# Ruby: Is there a right way to indent a case statement?

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, indentation

A number of blogs and tutorial have different indentations when they implement a case statement. Each have different indentation in reference to the 'when' lines. Is there a best practice for indenting when using a case loop?

Comment: There is not one right way or even just one best practice. There are probably just a couple of consistent ways that are most popular for readability. Here's just one example that is popular: https://github.com/styleguide/ruby

Answer (score 11):

The consensus is to indent `when` as the same level as `case`.

```
case sym
when :foo then ...
when :bar then ...
else ...
end
```

I think this is well established, and have not seen any authentic source that claims otherwise.

Comment: I have seen a few cases (not as often as your example) in which the `when` is indented by a couple of spaces. And then there are the cases where the `when` clause is not very simple and is multiple line which is not shown in your example.

Comment: `when` can expand beyond a line. It is the starting point that is important.

Comment: I believe this is sometimes called "Pickaxe notation" as it was introduced by the "Pickaxe book" (http://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby).

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I've seen it used.  The 'what happens in the event of the 'when' should be on the next line and indented.

```
case something
when 'a'
  what happens when 'a'
when 'b'
  what happens when 'b'
when 'c'
  what happens when 'c'
end
```